# need to parse JSON in Python3

Tags: json, parsing, python-3.6

am new to Python and need to parse the date and '4. close' from the following JSON. Would be very grateful for pointers how to do this the pythonic way.

```
{'2017-01-24': {'1. open': '207.8600',
                 '2. high': '209.4000',
                 '3. low': '207.7479',
                 '4. close': '208.9700',
                 '5. adjusted close': '208.0046',
                 '6. volume': '1940125',
                 '7. dividend amount': '0.00',
                 '8. split coefficient': '1.0000'},...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse JSON like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('path_of_file.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Moshe. Thats what i figured already actually. But whats the best way to slice it in order to get the date at the beginning and the value for '4. close'  so i can stick them into a CSV or a database?

Comment: Actually so easy. Sorry to bother you guys. the output is already a Python dictionary and the date is simply the key.

Comment: Yeah sorry, JSON is nearly universal as most programming languages have value key pairs